# How to get key value from JavaScript source map?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get a Source code name(key) for a particular javascript minified value, from a built angular project. I have Source Map and minified .js file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package named [maximize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maximize)